# Can GWT's RPC be used in a chrome extension to talk to the server?

Tags: gwt, google-chrome-extension, gwt-rpc

I would like to create a chrome extension with GWT. Is it possible to use GWT's RPC to communicate from the extension to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some rebinding is needed, based on [this package](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-bookmarks/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/com/google/gwt/user/rebind/rpc) in the [gwt-gae-bookmarks](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-bookmarks/) project (a GWT Chrome extension that talks to an App Engine app via GWT-RPC).